# Do creatures from outside the game go to the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Okay, so I was looking through some eldrazi to purchase and I came across [Spawnsire of Ulamog](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpawnsire%20of%20Ulamog%5d).

[image: Spawnspire of Ulamog card image]

I want to purchase it for my deck but I want to know how it works before I buy it. My question is, when you bring creatures from outside the game to the battlefield with this ability, when/if those creatures die, where do they go? Do they hit the graveyard or get removed from play?

Answer (score 4):

**Once a card has been brought into the game, it is treated like any card you have started the game with.**

The game rules make no distinction between cards from your deck and those that have been brought into the game after the game has started, they function exactly the same. Therefore, any card you bring into the game with  Spawnsire will do whatever it usually does, including going to the graveyard if the game rules require it.

The only difference is that you have to remove those cards from your deck before the next game starts, but that's a matter of tournament rules rather than game/match rules.

Comment: Cool, thank you, it's been some time since I've played :D